# Using oclazyload with $stateProvider giving controller is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, oclazyload, session-state-provider

I am very new to Angular and am trying to figure out authentication for a Flask Angular app. I think the issue is related to the fact that I am not defining the services.js dependency clearly.

I was getting [AngularJS error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthServiceProvider%20%3C-%20AuthService%20%3C-%20loginController). 
You can see a bit more information on [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400089/angular-flask-authentication-issues).

Now I am seeing `Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'loginController' is not a`. There is something wrong with the way services.js, app.js, controllers.js and directives.js are interacting. But I cannot figure out what the issue is. I believe it has to do with `config.py`. I think it has to do with how the controller is defined here:

```
         .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "static/views/login.html",
            controller: "loginController",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Login'},
        })
```

The template I am using also uses ocLazyLoad. I think a similar issue happened https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/182. Maybe this will help give some insight.

Here is my app structure:

[image]

Here is my services.js file:

```
angular.module('inspinia').factory('AuthService',
  ['$q', '$timeout', '$http',
  function ($q, $timeout, $http) {

    // create user variable
    var user = null;

    // return available functions for use in controllers
    return ({
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
      login: login,
      logout: logout,
      register: register
      getUserStatus: getUserStatus
    });

    function isLoggedIn() {
      if(user) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function login(email, password) {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a post request to the server
      $http.post('/api/login', {email: email, password: password})
        // handle success
        .success(function (data, status) {
          if(status === 200 && data.result){
            user = true;
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            user = false;
            deferred.reject();
          }
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

    function logout() {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a get request to the server
      $http.get('/api/logout')
        // handle success
        .success(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.resolve();
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

    function register(email, password) {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a post request to the server
      $http.post('/api/register', {email: email, password: password})
        // handle success
        .success(function (data, status) {
          if(status === 200 && data.result){
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            deferred.reject();
          }
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

    function getUserStatus() {
      return $http.get('/api/status')
      // handle success
      .success(function (data) {
        if(data.status){
          user = true;
        } else {
          user = false;
        }
      })
      // handle error
      .error(function (data) {
        user = false;
      });
    }

}]);
```

And here is app.js:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap'                 // Ui Bootstrap
    ])
})();
```

Config.js

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: true
    });

    $stateProvider

        .state('index', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/index",
            templateUrl: "static/views/common/content.html",
        })
        .state('index.main', {
            url: "/main",
            templateUrl: "static/views/main.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Example view' },
        })
        .state('index.minor', {
            url: "/minor",
            templateUrl: "static/views/minor.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Example view' },
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "static/views/login.html",
            controller: 'loginController',
            data: { pageTitle: 'Login'},
        })
}
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .config(config)
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
```

Controllers.py

```
angular.module('inspinia').controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.login = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call login from service
      AuthService.login($scope.loginForm.email, $scope.loginForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
                $location.path('/index/main');
                $scope.disabled = false;
                $scope.loginForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
                $scope.error = true;
                $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username and/or password";
                $scope.disabled = false;
                $scope.loginForm = {};
        });
```

Directives.js:

```
function pageTitle($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var listener = function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                // Default title - load on Dashboard 1
                var title = 'Transparencities';
                // Create your own title pattern
                if (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle) title = 'Transparencities | ' + toState.data.pageTitle;
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.text(title);
                });
            };
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', listener);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * sideNavigation - Directive for run metsiMenu on sidebar navigation
 */
function sideNavigation($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            // Call the metsiMenu plugin and plug it to sidebar navigation
            $timeout(function(){
                element.metisMenu();
            });
        }
    };
}

/**
 * iboxTools - Directive for iBox tools elements in right corner of ibox
 */
function iboxTools($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/common/ibox_tools.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            // Function for collapse ibox
            $scope.showhide = function () {
                var ibox = $element.closest('div.ibox');
                var icon = $element.find('i:first');
                var content = ibox.find('div.ibox-content');
                content.slideToggle(200);
                // Toggle icon from up to down
                icon.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
                ibox.toggleClass('').toggleClass('border-bottom');
                $timeout(function () {
                    ibox.resize();
                    ibox.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
                }, 50);
            },
                // Function for close ibox
                $scope.closebox = function () {
                    var ibox = $element.closest('div.ibox');
                    ibox.remove();
                }
        }
    };
}

/**
 * iboxTools with full screen - Directive for iBox tools elements in right corner of ibox with full screen option
 */
function iboxToolsFullScreen($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/common/ibox_tools_full_screen.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            // Function for collapse ibox
            $scope.showhide = function () {
                var ibox = $element.closest('div.ibox');
                var icon = $element.find('i:first');
                var content = ibox.find('div.ibox-content');
                content.slideToggle(200);
                // Toggle icon from up to down
                icon.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
                ibox.toggleClass('').toggleClass('border-bottom');
                $timeout(function () {
                    ibox.resize();
                    ibox.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
                }, 50);
            };
            // Function for close ibox
            $scope.closebox = function () {
                var ibox = $element.closest('div.ibox');
                ibox.remove();
            };
            // Function for full screen
            $scope.fullscreen = function () {
                var ibox = $element.closest('div.ibox');
                var button = $element.find('i.fa-expand');
                $('body').toggleClass('fullscreen-ibox-mode');
                button.toggleClass('fa-expand').toggleClass('fa-compress');
                ibox.toggleClass('fullscreen');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    };
}

/**
 * minimalizaSidebar - Directive for minimalize sidebar
*/
function minimalizaSidebar($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="" ng-click="minimalize()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.minimalize = function () {
                $("body").toggleClass("mini-navbar");
                if (!$('body').hasClass('mini-navbar') || $('body').hasClass('body-small')) {
                    // Hide menu in order to smoothly turn on when maximize menu
                    $('#side-menu').hide();
                    // For smoothly turn on menu
                    setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            $('#side-menu').fadeIn(400);
                        }, 200);
                } else if ($('body').hasClass('fixed-sidebar')){
                    $('#side-menu').hide();
                    setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            $('#side-menu').fadeIn(400);
                        }, 100);
                } else {
                    // Remove all inline style from jquery fadeIn function to reset menu state
                    $('#side-menu').removeAttr('style');
                }
            }
        }
    };
}


/**
 *
 * Pass all functions into module
 */
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .directive('pageTitle', pageTitle)
    .directive('sideNavigation', sideNavigation)
    .directive('iboxTools', iboxTools)
    .directive('minimalizaSidebar', minimalizaSidebar)
    .directive('iboxToolsFullScreen', iboxToolsFullScreen);
```

Comment: Can you show the `loginController` code? The module definition and such, not the internal stuff.

Comment: I updated to include config.py and the controller. Thank you!

Comment: `angular.module('inspinia').controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',`

Should have been

`angular.module('inspinia').controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', AuthService,`

`Authservice` should not have had any '' around it.

Comment: Now I am getting `Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'loginController' is not a`. Any ideas on what I can do next?

Comment: If the controller is lazy-loaded then you should refer to [the manual](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router) first, it clearly states how router should be used with ocLazyLoad.  For starters, I would suggest to get rid of lazy loading if you're 'very new to Angular', it provides questionable benefits and requires a good comprehension of what's going on. Because Angular wasn't designed with lazy loading in mind.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of how to fix it while still maintaining lazyLoading? It is part of the template I am using and getting rid of it would require a great number of changes.